# How to fix exif warnings and problems in JPG files?

Tags: android, exif

I wrote my own camera app. This app writes exif information in the jpg files. It works well but I have some problems with the `exifInferface` class, e.g., I get the following errors when re-read the JPG file:

```
Warning Invalid EXIF text encoding 
Warning Invalid size (8589934590) for IFD0 tag 0x8827 
Warning Bad IFD1 directory
```

I know that my IFD0 pointer at the exif-Information is broken. It may be that while writing the exif information the pointer is broken?

However, I've Googled and found nothing

I use this class to read an write the exif-informations:

```
public class ExifHelper {
private String aperature = null;
private String exposureTime = null;
private String flash = null;
private String focalLength = null;
private String gpsAltitude = null;
private String gpsAltitudeRef = null;
private String gpsDateStamp = null;
private String gpsLatitude = null;
private String gpsLatitudeRef = null;
private String gpsLongitude = null;
private String gpsLongitudeRef = null;
private String gpsProcessingMethod = null;
private String gpsTimestamp = null;
private String iso = null;
private String make = null;
private String model = null;
private String imageLength = null;
private String imageWidth = null;
private String orientation = null;
private String whiteBalance = null;  
private String exifVersion = null;
private String time = null;

private ExifInterface inFile = null;
private ExifInterface outFile = null;



final static String TAG = "ExifHelper";
/**
 * The file before it is compressed
 * 
 * @param filePath 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createInFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    this.inFile = new ExifInterface(filePath);       
}

/** 
 * The file after it has been compressed
 * 
 * @param filePath
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createOutFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    this.outFile = new ExifInterface(filePath);
}

/**
 * Reads all the EXIF data from the input file.
 */
public void readExifData() {
    this.aperature = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE);
    this.exposureTime = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME);
    this.flash = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
    this.focalLength = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH);
    this.gpsAltitude = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE);
    this.gpsAltitudeRef = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF);
    this.gpsDateStamp = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
    this.gpsLatitude = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
    this.gpsLatitudeRef = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
    this.gpsLongitude = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
    this.gpsLongitudeRef = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
    this.gpsProcessingMethod = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD);
    this.gpsTimestamp = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
    this.imageLength = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH);
    this.imageWidth = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH);
    this.iso = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO);
    this.make = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
    this.model = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
    this.orientation = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
    this.whiteBalance = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);  
    this.exifVersion = inFile.getAttribute("ExifVersion");
}

/**
 * Writes the previously stored EXIF data to the output file. 
 * @param pictureDate 
 * @param orientationValues 
 * @param accelValues 
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void writeExifData(String pictureDate) throws IOException {
    // Don't try to write to a null file
    if (this.outFile == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (this.aperature != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE, this.aperature);
    }
    if (this.exposureTime != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME, this.exposureTime);
    }
    if (this.flash != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH, this.flash);
    }
    if (this.focalLength != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH, this.focalLength);
    }
    if (this.gpsAltitude != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, this.gpsAltitude);
    }
    if (this.gpsAltitudeRef != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF, this.gpsAltitudeRef);
    }
    if (this.gpsDateStamp != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP, this.gpsDateStamp);
    }
    if (this.gpsLatitude != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, this.gpsLatitude);
    }
    if (this.gpsLatitudeRef != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, this.gpsLatitudeRef);
    }
    if (this.gpsLongitude != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, this.gpsLongitude);
    }
    if (this.gpsLongitudeRef != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, this.gpsLongitudeRef);
    }
    if (this.gpsProcessingMethod != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD, this.gpsProcessingMethod);
    }
    if (this.gpsTimestamp != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, this.gpsTimestamp);
    }
    if (this.iso != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO, this.iso);
    }
    if (this.make != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE, this.make);
    }
    if (this.model != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, this.model);
    }
    if (this.orientation != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, this.orientation);
    }
    if (this.whiteBalance != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE, this.whiteBalance);
    }
    if (this.exifVersion != null) {
        this.outFile.setAttribute("ExifVersion", this.exifVersion);
    }


    this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, this.imageLength);    
    this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, this.imageWidth);
    this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, pictureDate);
    String mString = exifRandomZahlen();
    this.outFile.setAttribute("UserComment", mString);

    this.outFile.saveAttributes();
}
```

I also write 2 images form the takepicture-method. One the original there is no problem and the second with modify exif informations. There is the problem with the exifinterface I think by writing it back to the JPG.

I used the tool DumpImage to view the exif informations. This tool is from the metaworking group (www.metadataworkinggroup.org)

So I have a big question, How I can fix this broken exif data? For example the IDF0 pointer
somebody know or have the same problem?

I get, for example, the Tag TAG_DATETIME two times in my exif information

this is the class for saveing the photo:

```
public class Photo extends Activity implements PictureCallback {
public interface OnPictureTakenListener {
    void pictureTaken(File pictureFile, File pictureFilePatched, String exifDateString);
}

private final Context context;
private OnPictureTakenListener listener;

public Photo(Context ourContext, OnPictureTakenListener theListener) {
    this.context = ourContext;
    this.listener = theListener;
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    Date date = new Date();

    File pictureFileDir = getDir();

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs())

    {
        Log.d(AndroidCamera.DEBUG_TAG,
                "Can't create directory to save image.");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat dateConverter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");

    String exifDateString = dateFormat.format(date);

    String datePicture = dateConverter.format(date); 

    String photoFile = "Picture_" + datePicture + ".jpg";

    String photoFilePatched = "Picture_" + datePicture + "_patched.jpg";

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    String filenamePatched =  pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFilePatched;

    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    File pictureFilePatched = new File (filenamePatched);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        FileOutputStream fosPatched = new FileOutputStream(pictureFilePatched);
        fos.write(data);
        fosPatched.write(data);
        fos.close();
        fosPatched.close();



        Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.d(AndroidCamera.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + " not saved: "
                + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    listener.pictureTaken(pictureFile,pictureFilePatched,exifDateString);
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

}


private File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    return new File(sdDir, "Camera");
}

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
```

}

here in main activity i call on one from the two pictures to write the exif infortmations:

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Photo(this,
            new Photo.OnPictureTakenListener() {
                public void pictureTaken(final File pictureFile,final File pictureFilePatched , final String date) {

                    final String fileName = pictureFile.getPath();
                    final String fileNamePatched = pictureFilePatched.getPath();
                    final String dateTime = date;
                    // don't start picture preview immediately, but a little
                    // delayed...
                    continueWithPreview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                                try {
                                // EXIF Matadata change
                                    ExifHelper exifHelper = new ExifHelper();
                                    exifHelper.createInFile(fileName);
                                    //EXIF Metadata read
                                    exifHelper.readExifData();
                                    exifHelper.createOutFile(fileNamePatched);  
                                    //Exif Metadata write
                                    exifHelper.writeExifData(dateTime);


                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("PictureActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            } 

                            if (null != camera)
                            {
                                camera.startPreview();
                                Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, "started!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    }, 2500);
```

Comment: Please show how you call the functions of this class on a file. Or on two files?

Comment: DumpImage? Is that an app? Not in Play store. I made an activity, put your ExifHelper in it, took a jpg file and made a copy of it. Then executed the five statements in the try block. The patched image is displayable but as I have no app to investigate the exif I transported the files top PC. Used IrfanView to look at the ExifInfo's. The original file has 43 exif tags and the patched one only 19. You are reading exif info from one file and then writing back this info with some changes to another file. Why dont you read it from the file itself?

Comment: Have you ever done a test where you read the exif info from a file and wrote it unchanged back to the same file?

Comment: i wirte more exif tag back ... but the exifinterface class dont add this to the others it overwrites the exif information. so only the exif tags from the exifhelper class will add to the exif metadata

Comment: dumpimage is tool from the page ;)

i found a good solution to this. the exifinterface class is underdeveloped for my problem.

now i use the apache sanselan lib to write/read/edit exif tags
(java lib on binary code for exif and other metadatafiles)