# Where should I put the Exifinterface in my camera app?

Tags: android, image, geolocation, exif

I'm making a camera app that takes and saves a picture in the SDcard. The idea is to store the pictures with date/location attributes. The date part works, but I don't know how to do the location one so I've been Googling and I discovered the Exif attributes. After read about them I know how they work but I have no idea how to place them in the code to make it work.

The part of the code where I think it should go it's attached below.

Thanks in advance!

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    };



    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FOTOS");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("FOTOS", "ERROR al crear el directorio");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss_ddMMyyyy").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
        }

        class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
                if(location != null)
                {
                    double plong = location.getLongitude();
                    double plat = location.getLatitude();
                    double palt = location.getAltitude();

                    textLat.setText(Double.toString(plat));
                    textLong.setText(Double.toString(plong));
                    textAlt.setText(Double.toString(palt));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: I do not see where you want to attach the code. And do not understand where you have exactly troubles.

Comment: I edited the code pointing the part of the code where i think it should go the exif calling.

My troubles are that I know what exifs are and do but I have no idea how to implement it in my app.

Comment: Who is calling getOutputMediaFile()? When and why?

Comment: You say `the date part works` and speak of attributes. But I see only a date in the filename. Can you manage to put a date in the Exif? Can you put aperture, shuttertime, camera model and so in it?

Comment: I updated the code with the missing code you were asking. I'm new on this, but once I make pictures and check the file I can see the date and the time the picture was taken, the camera model and the picture size.

Comment: If you can see the camera model and so then your picture file does already contain an exif info. Or not? In that case the byte[] data parameter would already contain the exif info.

Comment: Then if that exif does not contain the location you could add it just before creating the FileOutputStream.

Comment: I haven't added any exif info because I don't know how to do it. Any clue about how I could add it?

Comment: Please react on my comments/questions: does that file already have an exif? Because you said you could see model and so on.

Comment: Sorry, they do have an exif. But I haven't implemented any exif code so I don't know how they got there. Googleing a little it should get the location parameters as well and it doesn't. Excuse my ignorance I'm really new on this, but I really want to learn it!

Comment: It only has location when gps was on and location fixed. Are you sure it was?

Comment: location fixed where?

Comment: If you switch on the gps it can take up to ten minutes before the gps knows the location. Only then it is fixed. Try with de default camera app on your device.

Comment: Yes I've tried that. When I do it whit the camera app I get the complete location, however with my own app I don't.

Comment: Ok then you have to put the location in yourself. So first read the ExifInterface from data then add the location and then write the ExifInterface back to data. Upon which you save data as a file. If the ExifInterface cannot be determined from data then first save to file and apply all to that file.

Comment: Lately there was someone on this forum who was using ExifInterface but he did not succeed. Finally he used a different class. Don't know which one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521554/how-to-fix-exif-warnings-and-problems-in-jpg-files#comment36120846_23521554